# BigCommerce single click redirect

Tags: bigcommerce

I've created a BigCommerce draft single click app. I'm trying to respond to the app install with a simple php echo statement. I'm getting a redirect message though before my echo statement is displayed. This makes my response cumbersome to anyone that would use it. Why is this happening?